# Best method to fix the position of table cells to align with specific TH offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

I am new to programming but am trying to make a table like a TV EPG guide,say the  has 8pm,9pm,10

I need the TD cells to generate dynamically,and create each cell,at the correct position,a show starts at 8.30,the cell would start halfway between 8 and 9

I am currently using CSS

```
   {
position:fixed;
left:XXpx;
right:XXpx;
}
```

with jquery element offset position

Is there a better way of achieving this?

There is an old example from 2012 on here that says to use the above method,when I use Firebug it says the code has a "Deprication" alert,so I guess theres a more modern technique?

Comment: I would need to see more specific code to answer this clearly.  If you are reading the data dynamically through an AJAX call, JSON or XML, or is it a database query result?

Comment: sorry no I am simply creating the table from a JSON object,javascript gets the offset position,and calculates where to put itand writes the following cell to the document on loading, <td style="left:XXpx;right:XXpx"</td> ,as the start times are different for each row,it would look exactly like a TV EPG guide,but of course using that HTML code isn't very good,looking for a better way

Comment: why is the HTML code not acceptable?

Comment: I get a depricated alert in firebug,and as i said i am new but i guessed there is a better method,but thanks for your interest

Comment: which tag is it saying is deprecated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867321/absolute-position-table-cell-td-relative-to-table-row-tr      I am using the second example here,I realise it is the position:relative; was why I have gotten that message,thanks